# Intel Wireless N 7260 disconnects and asks for password

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I am on the ubuntu 14.04 live usb, and would like to dual boot with the pre-installed Windows 8.1 (i know how to do this), on my Toshiba e45t. The problem is whenever i try to connect to my WPA wifi (which all my other devices can connect to), every 2 seconds it drops the connection, and just reasks for the password. This is really annoying and you cannot even use the connection. Oddly enough, my wifi works on Windows 8.1, and Kali Linux. Here is my output from `dmesg`:

```
[ 1133.401930] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0
[ 1133.403428] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1133.471253] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1133.477224] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1133.477544] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1133.480164] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1133.548543] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1133.552080] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[ 1133.553468] wlan0: associated
[ 1134.093661] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1134.100155] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1134.100159] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1134.100162] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1134.100164] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1134.100165] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1134.100167] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1134.100169] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1136.167628] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0
[ 1136.169255] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1136.225755] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1136.228049] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1136.228228] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1136.232039] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1136.298984] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1136.302350] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[ 1136.303516] wlan0: associated
[ 1139.621330] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1139.629166] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1139.629176] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1139.629184] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1139.629191] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1139.629197] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1139.629203] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1139.629210] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1144.194955] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0
[ 1144.196720] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1144.248803] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1144.250721] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1144.251080] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1144.252097] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1144.349416] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1144.452161] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 3/3)
[ 1144.525915] wlan0: association with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 timed out
[ 1156.034860] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0
[ 1156.036483] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1156.038400] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1156.038748] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1156.040259] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1156.130877] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1156.133587] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[ 1156.134819] wlan0: associated
[ 1160.748371] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1160.755711] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1160.755718] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1160.755723] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1160.755727] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1160.755731] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1160.755734] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1160.755737] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1161.583118] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0
[ 1161.584798] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1161.647597] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1161.649523] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1161.649889] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1161.652143] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1161.724207] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1161.727741] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[ 1161.729057] wlan0: associated
[ 1167.476272] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1167.479397] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1167.479400] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1167.479402] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1167.479403] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1167.479404] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1167.479406] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1167.479407] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1168.311798] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0
[ 1168.313687] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1168.377440] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1168.379254] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1168.379420] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1168.380059] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1168.457185] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1168.460474] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[ 1168.461367] wlan0: associated
[ 1169.629523] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1169.634435] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1169.634440] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1169.634443] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1169.634446] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1169.634448] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1169.634450] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1169.634452] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1174.686159] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0
[ 1174.687813] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1174.732859] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1174.734744] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1174.735024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1174.736118] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 1174.803250] wlan0: associate with 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 1174.806558] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:b8:f5:f4:a0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[ 1174.807874] wlan0: associated
```

And my output from `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)

And from `lshw -class network`:
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 6b
       serial: 5c:51:4f:75:71:b4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:61 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

Is there anyway to upgrade the drivers? Kernel Upgrades? I've tried `iwconfig wlan0 power off`, that doesn't help.

Comment: I've had bad luck with inegrated intel wireless N cards.  I just pop an ath9k card in there and it works like a champ.

Comment: I also tried a realtek card, and it didn't work.

Comment: So, who told you atheros and realtek were the same thing?  I had a vendor at defcon try to tell me the same.  I wasn't an SE target.  Atheros or bust for me.

Comment: No one. But then the question is why do both of these cards work on Kali Linux? It must be a ubuntu or kernel problem

Comment: The problem is hacky patches that aren't accepted upstream.  So forks work, but mainline doesn't... at least until later when someone rewrites the patch to handle other conditions.

Comment: Ok. I might try to find the driver used on Kali and somehow download it for ubuntu. The driver might be hacky, but they work flawlessly. Btw the same wifi card works on windoze 8.1.

Comment: What would happen if I updated to the mainline kernel?

Comment: I can make a ford pento run flawlessly.  That doesn't make it a ferrari.  I wouldn't choose that engine swap either.

Comment: You dont get the point. I know its not an aethros, it is a good modern wireless card (2013) and made by Intel.

Comment: Then get the patches accepted upstream.

Comment: How? That seems like an immense task to do.

Comment: Show me a pull request and a denial with a list of reasons.  Then, I'll read that and quote it back to you.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what is a pull request?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Comment: ok, then how would you submit one for the main ubuntu repos?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20660/discussion-between-logern-and-hbdgaf).

Answer (score 1):

The encryption used by your wifi router/access point is the issue, from your post `iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use` so you need to eliminate WEP/TKIP from the encryption setting on the wifi router if you can.  What you want is WPA2-PSK or WPA2-AES only with no WEP or TKIP as they are older and not as secure

Comment: Why can my other devices connect then?

Comment: The other devices must be better tested on TKIP and allow for more variation from the standard than Ubuntu is.  I have seen too many posts on Linux websites with wireless issues that are solved by changing the encryption

Comment: Allowing for more deviation from the standard isn't operating to standard.  The fault isn't in the linux driver usually, it's in poor non-compliant versions that somehow work anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to enable WPA/TKIP on ubuntu?

Comment: It is enabled but doesn't always work.  It seems to depend on the router as I have been able to use it without issue with the wifi cards I have and I have 2 different 7260 cards